Is it required to have a space after semicolon in HTTP-Header content-disposition?
A WAF we are using is blocking responses from our webserver because of "Malformed HTTP-Header".
I suspect it is because of a "content-disposition" header set by the spring framework.
The header is looking like this: content-disposition: inline;filename=f.txt.
What is the problem with this? Is a space after the semicolon required?
I compared the HTTP-Headers of the blocked response with the Headers of other responses.
By this I came to the conclusion, that the issue must be with the "content-disposition" header.

the missing space may well be the problem. Here, all examples have the space: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition . Can you run an experiment with space?

Welcome to SO. If you did test with the space, and mention it in your question, we might upvote your question because "it shows research effort"
